# Telent: connection to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, pop3, mail-server

I use Rocky Linux.
When I do `telnet localhost 110`,
terminal response is
`Trying ::1...  telnet: connection to address ::1: Connection refused  Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: connection to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused`

But port 110 is already open.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Superuser](https://superuser.com) is a better place to ask about things like this. However, from that error, I can tell you that port 110 is *not* open (but without more info it's impossible to say why).

Comment: If do `firewall-cmd --list-all`
answer is `ports: 25/tcp 25/udp 110/tcp 110/udp 143/tcp 143/upd`

Comment: That just means the firewall isn't blocking it, not that it's open. Is anything listening on it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then, how can I open that?

Comment: Are you running something that listens on port 110? Like some sort of mail server program? See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1080199/i-cannot-connect-to-a-port-that-is-already-open-in-my-firewall) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/171043/ufw-says-a-port-is-open-everyone-else-disagrees).

Comment: I solved that problem in a different way. Thank you for your help.